# mysql combination count for nested type table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table:

```
BaseVar | BaseDate | BaseAttr | BaseValue | DependVar | DependDate | DependAttr | DependValue |

VarA        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Na         -1      
VarA        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Na          1   
VarA        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Na         -1   
VarB        01/01      Na            1        VarA        01/01         Na         -1      
VarB        01/01      Br            1        VarB        01/01         Na          1   
VarB        01/01      Hs            1        VarC        01/01         Na         -1   
VarC        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Na         -1      
VarC        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Na          1   
VarC        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Na         -1

VarA        01/02      Na            1        VarA        01/02       Na            1      
VarA        01/02      Br            1        VarB        01/02       Na           -1   
VarA        01/02      Hs            1        VarC        01/02       Na           -1   
VarB        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Na            1      
VarB        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Na           -1   
VarB        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Na           -1   
VarC        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Na            1      
VarC        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Na           -1   
VarC        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Na           -1

.
.
.
.
.
All the way to 12/30
Then again for:

BaseVar | BaseDate | BaseAttr | BaseValue | DependVar | DependDate | DependAttr | DependValue |
VarA        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Br         -1      
VarA        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Br          1   
VarA        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Br         -1   
VarB        01/01      Na            1        VarA        01/01         Br         -1      
VarB        01/01      Br            1        VarB        01/01         Br          1   
VarB        01/01      Hs            1        VarC        01/01         Br         -1   
VarC        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Br         -1      
VarC        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Br          1   
VarC        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Br         -1

VarA        01/02      Na            1        VarA        01/02       Br            1      
VarA        01/02      Br            1        VarB        01/02       Br           -1   
VarA        01/02      Hs            1        VarC        01/02       Br           -1   
VarB        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Br            1      
VarB        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Br           -1   
VarB        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Br           -1   
VarC        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Br            1      
VarC        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Br           -1   
VarC        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Br           -1


.
.
.
.
.
All the way to 12/30
Then again for:


BaseVar | BaseDate | BaseAttr | BaseValue | DependVar | DependDate | DependAttr | DependValue |
VarA        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Hs         -1      
VarA        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Hs          1   
VarA        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Hs         -1   
VarB        01/01      Na            1        VarA        01/01         Hs         -1      
VarB        01/01      Br            1        VarB        01/01         Hs          1   
VarB        01/01      Hs            1        VarC        01/01         Hs         -1   
VarC        01/01      Na           -1        VarA        01/01         Hs         -1      
VarC        01/01      Br           -1        VarB        01/01         Hs          1   
VarC        01/01      Hs           -1        VarC        01/01         Hs         -1

VarA        01/02      Na            1        VarA        01/02       Hs            1      
VarA        01/02      Br            1        VarB        01/02       Hs           -1   
VarA        01/02      Hs            1        VarC        01/02       Hs           -1   
VarB        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Hs            1      
VarB        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Hs           -1   
VarB        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Hs           -1   
VarC        01/02      Na           -1        VarA        01/02       Hs            1      
VarC        01/02      Br           -1        VarB        01/02       Hs           -1   
VarC        01/02      Hs           -1        VarC        01/02       Hs           -1


.
.
.
.
.
All the way to 12/30
```

The result I would like to obtain is:

```
BaseVar | BaseAttr| BaseValue| BaseAttrCount() | DependVar | DependAttr | DependantValue| DependAttrCount()|

VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Hs         1            cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Hs         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarA         Na             -1               cnt

VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Hs         1            cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Hs         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarB         Na             -1               cnt

VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Na         1            cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Na         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Hs         1            cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Hs         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             1                cnt
VarA        Br         1            cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt
VarA        Br         -1           cnt            VarC         Na             -1               cnt

(Next sequence would be : )

VarA                                                 VarA       Br

After all those are done:

VarA                                                 VarA       Hs

Then:

VarB                                                 VarA       Na

Then:

VarB                                                 VarA       Br

Then:

VarB                                                 VarA       Hs

and so on until it would reach:

VarC                                                 VarC       Hs
```

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to get the each combination of dependant variables that occur when a base variable occurs on a day. At the end I would like to have a count
which counts all the dependant combinations that occur when a base combination occurred. For example lets say, (BaseVar)VarA + (BaseAttr)Br +  (BaseValue)1 occurred 50 times, and when this combination occurred,
(DependVar)VarC + (DependAttr)Na +  (DependValue)-1 occurred 18 times, (DependVar)VarB + (DependAttr)Br +(DependValue)-1 occurred 11 times, (DependVar)VarB + (DependAttr)Na +(DependValue)1 occurred 5 times and so on.
There will be A LOT of rows because of the combinations. I have tried different groupings and right joins but can't get it work.

Jfiddle of attempt: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17ddd/1

Comment: Add the SQL statement that got the closest, and then explain what results you got with it. ie what did you get right and what was wrong.

Comment: [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17ddd/1   I tried grouping, but it shows only baseVarA

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.BaseCount, B.BaseVar, B.BaseAttr, B.BaseValue, COUNT(*) as DependCount, D.DependVar, D.DependAttr, D.DependValue from
(SELECT count(*) AS BaseCount, BaseVar, BaseAttr, BaseValue
  FROM Weather
  GROUP BY BaseVar, BaseAttr, BaseValue) AS B
JOIN Weather AS D
ON B.BaseVar = D.BaseVar AND B.BaseAttr = D.BaseAttr AND B.BaseValue = D.BaseValue
GROUP BY B.BaseVar, B.BaseAttr, B.BaseValue, D.DependVar, D.DependAttr, D.DependValue
ORDER BY B.BaseVar, B.BaseAttr, B.BaseValue
```

The inner select groups by each basevar-baseattr-basevalue combination then the join breaks down each one with the matching dependvar-dependattr-dependvalue combination.

Comment: Similar to what I was going to propose, but the OP mentions "when a base variable occurs on a day", and you have no date grouping here.

Comment: So you want this report for a single date? Or do you want it grouped by dates?